# docker set cpuset error when use lxc driver

Tags: docker, lxc

I run docker use lxc driver(my docker version: 1.0, OS: centos 6.5). but run a container failure when I set cpuset, the error message as follow.

```
docker run --net=none --privileged=true --cpuset="0,1" -m 512m -it centos-mini /bin/bash
lxc-start: Permission denied - write /cgroup/cpuset/lxc/c9d82fec23b4a43e4cd1c200a7ba1453afe34378c4d489f3e932afd88968e87b/cpuset.cpus : Permission denied
lxc-start: Error setting cpuset.cpus to 0,1 for lxc/c9d82fec23b4a43e4cd1c200a7ba1453afe34378c4d489f3e932afd88968e87b

lxc-start: failed to setup the cgroups for 'c9d82fec23b4a43e4cd1c200a7ba1453afe34378c4d489f3e932afd88968e87b'
lxc-start: failed to spawn 'c9d82fec23b4a43e4cd1c200a7ba1453afe34378c4d489f3e932afd88968e87b'
```

What is the problem here? How to resolve this problem? Thanks very much.

Comment: You need to run docker as root. If you got this running, please post an update. I'm encountering the same problem.